# Playing with syscall table from LKM

Tags: c, linux, module, linux-kernel

I'm overriding `SYS_READ` from the syscall table in Linux (3.x) but I'm having some troubles when unloading the module itself.
I first load my module which finds the syscall table, then enables `RW`, overrides `SYS_READ` with my own `SYS_READ` function (which in fact doesn't do anything else than calling the original `SYS_READ`), then I wait a few moments, and then unload the module. On the unload method of my module I restore the original `SYS_READ` function back in the syscall table and set back the syscall table to `RO`.

The original `SYS_READ` function is restored properly, but I get this when I unload the module: http://pastebin.com/JyYpqYgL

What am I missing? Should I be doing something more after restoring the real `SYS_READ` ?

EDIT: GitHub link to the project: https://github.com/alexandernst/procmon

EDIT:

This is how I get the syscall table address:

```
void **sys_call_table;

struct idt_descriptor{
    unsigned short offset_low;
    unsigned short selector;
    unsigned char zero;
    unsigned char type_flags;
    unsigned short offset_high;
} __attribute__ ((packed));


struct idtr{
    unsigned short limit;
    void *base;
} __attribute__ ((packed));


void *get_sys_call_table(void){
    struct idtr idtr;
    struct idt_descriptor idtd;
    void *system_call;
    unsigned char *ptr;
    int i;

    asm volatile("sidt %0" : "=m" (idtr));
    memcpy(&idtd, idtr.base + 0x80 * sizeof(idtd), sizeof(idtd));
    system_call = (void*)((idtd.offset_high<<16) | idtd.offset_low);
    for(ptr=system_call, i=0; i<500; i++){
        if(ptr[0] == 0xff && ptr[1] == 0x14 && ptr[2] == 0x85)
            return *((void**)(ptr+3));
        ptr++;
    }

    return NULL;
}

sys_call_table = get_sys_call_table();
```

And this is how I set RW/RO:

```
unsigned long set_rw_cr0(void){
    unsigned long cr0 = 0;
    unsigned long ret;
    asm volatile("movq %%cr0, %%rax" : "=a"(cr0));
    ret = cr0;
    cr0 &= 0xfffffffffffeffff;
    asm volatile("movq %%rax, %%cr0" : : "a"(cr0));
    return ret;
}

void set_ro_cr0(unsigned long val){
    asm volatile("movq %%rax, %%cr0" : : "a"(val));
}
```

Finally, this is how I define my syscalls and change the syscall table:

```
asmlinkage ssize_t (*real_sys_read)(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);
asmlinkage ssize_t hooked_sys_read(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);

//set my syscall
real_sys_read = (void *)sys_call_table[__NR_read];
sys_call_table[__NR_read] = (void *)hooked_sys_read;

//restore real syscall
sys_call_table[__NR_read] = (void *)real_sys_read;
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to set/unset the syscall table?

Comment: @MatsPetersson better, I can post the link to the github page :) Please check my edit

Comment: No, that is not at all better... Because it will go stale in a few hours or days time, so someone coming back to look at this next week, next year, etc will not see the same thing as I see if I look at it now. The point about SO is to share problems and solutions, not personal problem solving. Also, by posting the RELEVANT bits of code, means I don't have to wade through your code to try to figure out which parts are the ones you are working on right now, and which parts are irrellevant. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Oh, yes indeed, I beg a pardon. You're right, I'll edit my question adding just the relevan code. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: And while you are at it, please post the whole oops message. It may not be relevant/useful to you, but it may help me or someone else understand what is actually going on.

Comment: Not an answer, but worth mentioning: as I understand it, this kind of hack is explicitly not supported usage for Linux kernel modules, and not guaranteed to work in the future. You might want to consider a different approach to whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: @R.. oh, no worries, I'm doing it for fun, not for profit nor future proof :)

Comment: +1 for the useful edit.  It is now an interesting question.

Comment: Just 2 up votes for this question,I believe it deserve more up votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to unload the module that intercepts system calls aware of the situations when some process still in system call handler and your code (module's text segment) goes away from the memory. That leads to page fault as when the process returns from some kernel function (that sleeps) into your code the code doesn't exists anymore.

So, correct module unloading scheme must check for the processess that may sleeps in hooked system calls. Unloading possible only if there are no one process that sleeps in the syscall hook.

**UPD**

Please, see the patch that proves my theory. It adds the atomic counter that increments and decrements when the `hooked_sys_read` calls. So as I supposed there is a process that still waiting in `read_sys_read` while you module have been unloaded. This patch show that with the `printk(read_counter)` and it prints `1` for me which means that someone doesn't decrement the `read_counter`.

http://pastebin.com/1yLBuMDY

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but how can I check which processes are sleeping? And also, how can I make sure they triggered the syscall I hijacked? (as going from sleeping -> working doesn't mean the process called the restored syscall)

Comment: Use the atomic counter that increments before the hook called and decrements after the call completed. When unloading check all the counters for `zero`. If some of them doesn't equals to `zero` then sleep a lot and repeat the operation.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that, but it seems Mats's answer has to do something with the problem. I'm still trying to figure out how to flush cache/mem before completely unloading the module.

Comment: I think the main point here is that OTHER processor(core)s may not see a read-only pages as "I need to snoop this memory". So when the data is changed for that item, the data for that memory is not re-loaded when it should be. So the key here is to flush the OTHER processor's caches. CPUID drains the pipeline, but does not flush caches.

Comment: Well, it seems that your point may be valid. I'll suggest to the author to use `stop_machine` for the kernel patching.

Comment: Thank you for the patch :) As soon as I get home I'll try it and if I get the same result I'll write a patch for Procmon

Comment: It worked!!! See #8 in Procmon (in Github). Send me your address so I can get you a beer :P

Answer (score 1):

Here's some random ramblings, I'm far from sure any/all of it makes much sense, but it's getting late, and I'd rather write it down and get to bed than try to figure out exactly which (if any) is actually the problem. Hopefully something will help:

I take it you have checked that your restore actually restores the pointer - e.g. print the content of `sys_call_table[__NR_read]`?

I would definitely restore CR0 by or-ing back the bit you cleared, rather than restoring an old value - it may not matter most of the time, but there are other bits in CR0 that may change from time to time - probably only really the TS bit, but that's bad enough - getting some random restore of stale floating point or missing a floating point restore is a bad thing [and guess how easy it is to figure out that the reason some long-running math suddenly got completely incorrect results because your code unloaded a few hours earlier?]. That's almost certainly not why your code is crashing, but it will almost certainly cause problems at one point or another if you load/unload the module enough times. [Also, make sure you are not swapping between processors when you change CR0 - probably best to do some sort of locking to ensure you stay on the same processor whilst doing the whole update `sys_call_table` stuff].

I think the reason your code is crashing, however, is lack of cache-flushing (the OS isn't expecting this memory to change - and the process sees it as read only, so it shouldn't need to be checked for invalidation]. You need to flush the caches on all processors for the sys_call_table entry. I'm not sure what the easiest/best way to do that is. I think `void flush_icache_range(unsigned long start, unsigned long end)` is the call you need - but I'm not sure if that's a current or an old function. From here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cachetlb.txt

As I said initially, this is more ramblings than actually looking into how things work deep inside the kernel, etc. Time for my beauty sleep - I need as much of that as I can get... ;)

Comment: Thank you for the extended reply! About the 1st point, __NR_read gets restored. About the 2nd one, I do restore the value of CR0, I just didn't show it in the code I wrote here. About the 3rd, yes, that could actually be causing the Oops. Anyways, is ```flush_icache_range``` exported? I grep-ed for it in the kernel but there doesn't seem to be code using it.

Comment: What I meant with CR0 is that you should not "restore" the old value, you should OR-back in the  WP bit, just like you use and/mask to get rid of it. Not sure what is the best way to flush the cache...

Comment: This post is about CPU migration and SMP `cr0`-safe operations: http://vulnfactory.org/blog/2011/08/12/wp-safe-or-not/

Comment: @MatsPetersson: `sys_call_table` items are long sized and properly aligned, so the `x86` processor atomically operates on their contents. IIRC, `flush_icache_range` on `x86` does nothing. So, I think that it's not a cache issue.

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier, I wasn't in the contry. I just tried the current code on a Virtual Box with 1 assigned CPU and the bug is still there so maybe that isn't a flush bug? /cc @IlyaMatveychikov

Comment: Hmm, could be something else, I suppose.